# Do applications built with Mono run on .NET?

Tags: .net, mono

I have been wondering about this for quite awhile, but I havent found a concrete answer, only for the other way around (does .net apps run on mono).

I notice most Mono-apps are quite large when downloading, is that because they ship the Mono-runtime too? Or is that just a better-safe-than-sorry precaution?

Does applications built for Windows run on the .NET Framework, without having Mono installed, nor included in the executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono compiler generates the same format executables as the .NET compiler, so yes, Mono-compiled programs should run on .NET as well.

Comment: And what about the runtime library? I would guess that many Mono applications use some of the libraries that are not inside the .NET BCL.

Comment: Well, mscorlib should be the same; if you rely on external libraries or parts that don't exist in other implementations, e.g. the Microsoft.* or Mono.* namespaces, then there are quite obvious portability problems.

Comment: Short and precise answer, thank you! I suppose the mono apps that are huge ship with the runtime to make sure it works?

Comment: That's likely. Applications written in Java do the same, or those in interpreted languages like Python, Perl, Ruby, etc. It's far easier to bundle the runtime than trying to get your users to find and install it (from a UX perspective).